# Java 8 / Lambdas / Streams : Subclassing Function<T,R> leads to issues with andThen() method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

As a more descriptive interface, I would like to create the following:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Dial extends Function<Double,Double> {}
```

However, when I try composing `Dial` instances like this:

```
public class DialExample {
    public Dial dialMult (double mult) {
        return (i -> i * mult);
    }

    public void myTest () {
        // Yes
        Function<Double,Double> f1 = dialMult(3.0).andThen(dialMult(4.0));

        // No
        Dial d1 = dialMult(3.0).andThen(dialMult(4.0));    
    }
}
```

The code under the `// No` comment gives me the following compilation error:

> Error:(22, 40) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type
>   variable(s) V exist so that
>   java.util.function.Function conforms to
>   lambdas.Dial

Certainly the code under the `// Yes` comment works, but it defeats the purpose of having a descriptive `Dial` interface in the first place.

I have a few questions:

- What is it in the design/implementation of Java generics and lambdas that leads
  to this issue?
- Is there a workaround?
- Is it even a good practice to
  subclass `Function<Double,Double>` as a descriptive interface like mine
  or should I be avoiding this in the first place?

Comment: A `Dial` is a `Function<Double, Double>`, but a `Function<Double, Double>` is not necessarily a `Dial`.

Comment: It is better practice to use a `DoubleUnaryOperator`, or, at the very least, `UnaryOperator<Double>`, rather than `Function<Double, Double>`. Your `Dial` interface is basically a clone of the `DoubleUnaryOperator` interface, but without primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `default` method inherited from `Function` is declared to return `Function` and that doesn’t change when invoking the `default` method via a sub-`interface`. Note that `Function.andThen` allows to combine your `Dial` instance with an arbitrary `Function` returning a different type creating a `Function` that is not compatible to your `Dial`’s functional signature:

```
Function<Double,String> f=dialMult(3.0).andThen(Object::toString);
```

But if the types match you can convert the `Function` on-the-fly:

```
Dial d1 = dialMult(3.0).andThen(dialMult(4.0))::apply;
```

---

Alternatively you can create your own `andThen` method. Note that this method does not override the `Function.andThen(Function)` method as that would require to limit the allowed type parameters for the second function which would be an invalid parameter narrowing. But for combining two `Dial` instances (or a `Dial` instance with a `UnaryOperator<Double>`) it works.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Dial extends UnaryOperator<Double> {
    public default Dial andThen(UnaryOperator<Double> after) {
        return d->after.apply(apply(d));
    }
}
```

---

Since it seems the explanation why the method above does not override `Function.andThen(Function)` was too brief, so let me go into detail:

As said in the beginning, the `andThen` method inherited from `Function` allows a parameter function with an arbitrary return type which was illustrated with an example using a function that returns `String` rather than `Double`. When applying the type parameters the `Dial` specifies for its super type, the effective signature becomes:

```
public interface Dial extends UnaryOperator<Double> {
    @Override
    public default <R>
    Function<Double, R> andThen(Function<? super Double, ? extends R> after) {
        return UnaryOperator.super.andThen(after);
    }
}
```

when overriding this method, you can declare a more specific return type, i.e. a sub-interface of `Function`, however, it must be type compatible with `Function<Double, R>` which is not the case for `Dial` as `Dial` extends `Function<Double,Double>`. That would require to limit the parameter to allow only `Double` for `R` which is not allowed. To be a valid substitute for `Function<Double, R>` the sub-interface must be itself generic to be parametrizable with `<R>`.

Comment: The second half of your answer ("Alternatively...") worked perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that you can also do a simple covariant override of `andThen` where you refine only the return type and hold the arguments constant.  Then this is indeed an override, simply with covariant return type (this feature was added in Java 5 and applies equally well to default methods.)

Comment: @Brian Goetz: as explained in my answer, that’s exactly what you can *not*. `andThen` accepts an arbitrary function with an arbitrary return type and must return a `Function` with a return type compatible to the second function. Therefore you can’t override it to return an instance of `Dial` which invariably extends `Function<Double,Double>`. That would require to limit the parameter which is `Function<Double,R>` to `Function<Double,Double>` which is not possible.

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation to my answer…

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `andThen` is

```
default <V> Function<T,V> andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V> after)
```

What you'd need is

```
default <V> TypeOfThis andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V> after)
```

which is at least hard to express in Java and is less flexible.

Could you try re-implementing `andThen` in Dial, using Dial as return value? May work...

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `andThen` can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). It clearly says that `andThen` returns `Function` and not `Dial`.

Java has no good way to make type safe aliases to types.

Comment: How. I dont see a way to Do this without amending Function interface by adding one more generic parameter which will represent real derived interface. It will look ugly